# Play mp4 file from URL on android

Tags: android, mp4

I've been researching for some time now, and all the questions I can find point to mp4 'hinting' but I have no control over the videos.

I was about to give up when i discovered that MX video player on the android market can somehow play these mp4 urls I have. So at the moment I use an intent to launch the urls in mx player but I'd much rather display the video within my app.

Any ideas how mx player does this would be great,

Thanks

Comment: Refer this [link](http://asmncl.blogspot.in/2012/04/android-live-streaming-using-video-view.html) i had pasted the whole code for playing the mp4 videos in your app by creating a videoview and you might minor error you can manually remove that error.

Answer (score 9):

Check this. It will help you.

```
String LINK = "http://www.boisestatefootball.com/sites/default/files/videos/original/01%20-%20coach%20pete%20bio_4.mp4";
setContentView(R.layout.video);
VideoView videoView =(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
mc.setAnchorView(videoView);
mc.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
Uri video = Uri.parse(LINK);
videoView.setMediaController(mc);
videoView.setVideoURI(video);
videoView.requestFocus();
videoView.start();
```