# can't play .mp4 file from Url link

Tags: android, android-videoview

I am working to play video file from a URL link. My URL looks like:

```
// this not works
https://vimeo.com/81995018
```

I am  tested below link it work, what some answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10870660/play-mp4-file-from-url-on-android/12105553#12105553).

```
// it works fine
String LINK = "http://www.boisestatefootball.com/sites/default/files/videos/original/01%20-%20coach%20pete%20bio_4.mp4";
```

When i run with my link get an error in log cat which looks :

```
12-18 12:25:19.207: D/MediaPlayer(1578): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
12-18 12:25:19.217: E/MediaPlayer(1578): error (1, -2147483648)
12-18 12:25:19.277: E/MediaPlayer(1578): Error (1,-2147483648)
12-18 12:25:19.277: D/VideoView(1578): Error: 1,-2147483648
```

My Activity class as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Context context = this;
VideoView videoView;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // it works fine
    // String LINK =
    // "http://www.boisestatefootball.com/sites/default/files/videos/original/01%20-%20coach%20pete%20bio_4.mp4";

    // this not works :(
    String LINK = "https://vimeo.com/81995018";

    videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView_test);
    MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
    mc.setAnchorView(videoView);
    mc.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
    Uri video = Uri.parse(LINK);
    videoView.setMediaController(mc);
    videoView.setVideoURI(video);
    videoView.requestFocus();
    videoView.start();

}
}
```

I am also trying to get the codec/format/specification of the given video link,to check whether my **Android 2.3.4** **Sony XPeria-New** run it or not. But can't get this also.

Need someone's super knock. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This [Link](http://www.wondershare.com/convert-video-audio/android-video-format.html) shows what files Android phones and tablets support, with both codec and filename extension information provided. However, an Android application can use media codecs either provided by any Android-powered device, or additional media codecs developed by third-party companies. Therefore, if you want to play videos on Android, find a multi-format video player or convert videos to Android compatible formats.

See this Android Supported Media Formats http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html.

Comment: am also trying to get the codec/format/specification of the given video link,to check whether my Android 2.3.4 *Sony XPeria-New* run it or not. But can't get this also. @Murali

Comment: @shihab_returns You need convert this video to android support file for example: For SD - Standard Definition: H.264 video codec, video bitrate up to 500 Kbps, resolution 480x360 px, 30 frames per second, AAC-LC audio codec, audio bitrate up to 128 Kbps, stereo audio with .m4v, .mp4, and .mov video container

Answer (score 1):

This is only for running VimeoVideo

Use this two class.

```
    package com.example.newsolution;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.KeyEvent;

    public class Test extends Activity {

        HTML5WebView mWebView;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            mWebView = new HTML5WebView(this);

            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                mWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
            } else {    
    //            mWebView.loadUrl("http://player.vimeo.com/video/27244727");
                mWebView.loadUrl("http://player.vimeo.com/video/81995018");
            }

            setContentView(mWebView.getLayout());
        }

        @Override
        public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            mWebView.saveState(outState);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            mWebView.stopLoading();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                if (mWebView.inCustomView()) {
                    mWebView.hideCustomView();
                //  mWebView.goBack();
                    //mWebView.goBack();
                    return true;
                }

            }
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }
    }
    package com.example.newsolution;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class HTML5WebView extends WebView {

    private Context                             mContext;
    private MyWebChromeClient                   mWebChromeClient;
    private View                                mCustomView;
    private FrameLayout                         mCustomViewContainer;
    private WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback  mCustomViewCallback;

    private FrameLayout                         mContentView;
    private FrameLayout                         mBrowserFrameLayout;
    private FrameLayout                         mLayout;

    static final String LOGTAG = "HTML5WebView";

    private void init(Context context) {
        mContext = context;     
        Activity a = (Activity) mContext;

        mLayout = new FrameLayout(context);

        mBrowserFrameLayout = (FrameLayout) LayoutInflater.from(a).inflate(R.layout.custom_screen, null);
        mContentView = (FrameLayout) mBrowserFrameLayout.findViewById(R.id.main_content);
        mCustomViewContainer = (FrameLayout) mBrowserFrameLayout.findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_custom_content);

        mLayout.addView(mBrowserFrameLayout, COVER_SCREEN_PARAMS);

        // Configure the webview
        WebSettings s = getSettings();
        s.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        s.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
        s.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        s.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
      //  s.setSavePassword(true);
        s.setSaveFormData(true);
        s.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebChromeClient = new MyWebChromeClient();
        setWebChromeClient(mWebChromeClient);

        setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

        // enable navigator.geolocation 
       // s.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
       // s.setGeolocationDatabasePath("/data/data/org.itri.html5webview/databases/");

        // enable Web Storage: localStorage, sessionStorage
        s.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        mContentView.addView(this);
    }

    public HTML5WebView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public HTML5WebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public HTML5WebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context);
    }

    public FrameLayout getLayout() {
        return mLayout;
    }

    public boolean inCustomView() {
        return (mCustomView != null);
    }

    public void hideCustomView() {
        mWebChromeClient.onHideCustomView();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            if ((mCustomView == null) && canGoBack()){
                goBack();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    private class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
        private Bitmap      mDefaultVideoPoster;
        private View        mVideoProgressView;

        @Override
        public void onShowCustomView(View view, WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback callback)
        {
            //Log.i(LOGTAG, "here in on ShowCustomView");
            HTML5WebView.this.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            // if a view already exists then immediately terminate the new one
            if (mCustomView != null) {
                callback.onCustomViewHidden();
                return;
            }

            mCustomViewContainer.addView(view);
            mCustomView = view;
            mCustomViewCallback = callback;
            mCustomViewContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onHideCustomView() {
            System.out.println("customview hideeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee");
            if (mCustomView == null)
                return;        

            // Hide the custom view.
            mCustomView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            // Remove the custom view from its container.
            mCustomViewContainer.removeView(mCustomView);
            mCustomView = null;
            mCustomViewContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mCustomViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();

            HTML5WebView.this.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            HTML5WebView.this.goBack();
            //Log.i(LOGTAG, "set it to webVew");
        }


        @Override
        public View getVideoLoadingProgressView() {
            //Log.i(LOGTAG, "here in on getVideoLoadingPregressView");

            if (mVideoProgressView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
                mVideoProgressView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_loading_progress, null);
            }
            return mVideoProgressView; 
        }

         @Override
         public void onReceivedTitle(WebView view, String title) {
            ((Activity) mContext).setTitle(title);
         }

         @Override
         public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
             ((Activity) mContext).getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS, newProgress*100);
         }

         @Override
         public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
             callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
         }
    }


    static final FrameLayout.LayoutParams COVER_SCREEN_PARAMS =
        new FrameLayout.LayoutParams( ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
}
```

[Details](https://github.com/droid28/VimeoVideo) is here